# Await doesn't seem to work, Async (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mean

So I'm trying to create a function which checks if the user exists in the database, if they don't it then goes and imports them to the database. I'm trying to use the await feature so it waits for the function to be completed before moving on.

```
const doesUserExist = (id) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db('db');
        var users = dbo.collection('user');
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            users.findOne({'id': id}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('User: ', user);
                if (user === null) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

const userLogin = async (user) => { // User login function
    var id = String(user.id);

    // Check if the user exists

    var doesExist = await doesUserExist(id);
    console.log(doesExist);
    if(doesExist===undefined){
        console.log('ERROR: Exist is empty');
        return;
    }
    if(doesExist===false){
        console.log(`User with the id ${id} does not exist.`);
        addUser(user);
    } else {
        console.log(`User with the id ${id} does exist.`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning a Promise from the `doesUserExist` function.

You are only returning a Promise in the callback of the MongoClient `connect` function.

You have to refactor your code this way :

```
const doesUserExist = (steamid) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db('treehouse');
            var users = dbo.collection('users');
            users.findOne({'steamid': steamid}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('User: ', user);
                if (user === null) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now, the  `doesUserExist` function is returning a Promise that is resolved in the `findOne` callback.